# How do you publish a web app using Azure pipe line?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

In Visual Studio (2019) I can build my app and publish it locally. I can then copy the files manually to my server and everything is fine.

This is the file list using Manual zip/unzip method :)
[image: File List using Manual zip/unzip method]

This is the file list using Azure Pipeline method :(
[image: File list using Azure Pipeline method]

I amusing C# Asp.Net-Mvc Core 2.2, I'll be moving to 3.1 shortly but would like to solve this before I move on.

I'm trying to set up an Azure pipeline as I use VSTS-GIT for my source control. My YAML file is below.

My manual process is

1. Build the application in Visual Studio (2019)
2. Publish the application for a local folder on my machine
3. Zip the folder
4. Copy the zip to the ftp site
5. Unzip the file on the ftp

The website then works fine. The only thing I don't need from the pipeline is the zip/unzip

The pipeline runs fine and it uploads files to my server but the website doesn't work and the files that are uploaded aren't the same as the manual method. The error is `HTTP Error 500.31 - Failed to load ASP.NET Core runtime`, but I think that's a red-herring because the exact same website works perfectly fine if I upload files manually.

I've been at this a while now, reading all sorts of articles and videos but I can't seem to get it to work. I know I am doing something wrong but I don't know what.

I'm struggling to find the right settings to do the same thing with Azure Dev Ops. I've read through this site extensively [Azure Dev Ops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/?view=azure-devops) but can't seem to find the right settings, can anyone help, please?

```
trigger:
- local-1

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Publish
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: True
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: false

- task: FtpUpload@2
  inputs:
    credentialsOption: 'inputs'
    serverUrl: 'ftp://ftp.xxxxxxx.com/'
    username: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    password: 'xxxxxxxxxx'
    rootDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'  
    filePatterns: '**'
    remoteDirectory: '/'
    clean: false
    cleanContents: false
    preservePaths: false
    trustSSL: false
```

Comment: It's not my votedown your question. But I guess the reason why others did this is that you said that the cause of the problem is that the result of azure pipeline FTP is inconsistent with your manual result, but you did not give any information in this regard, so that no one can know where the problem is. So you need to share some evidence of your different results in the two ways, such as screenshots and what are the results you want?

Comment: OK I will see what other information can provide without making the article too big. Simply put I am trying to replicate my manual process in the Azure pipeline. I'll add that to the question

Comment: Don't worry about the length of the article, anyone who wants to help you will patiently read your question. What you currently need to provide is the difference between the results of the two methods?

Comment: To do that I would have to list the file contents or attach zip files and that's a lot of information. It would also mean sharing confidential information so it not really practical. I'll see if I can do a screenshot or something

Comment: We also do not recommend you share all the information, which is very dangerous. You only need to share the files with differences, a screenshot is enough, and the file itself is not required.

Comment: Thank you. I have added some screenshots

Comment: All of those .js, .png, etc. files; where are they when you upload manually? In wwwroot? In runtimes? It looks like the FTP task might not be uploading folders correctly. You have `preservePaths: false` in your FTP task; should it be `true`?

Comment: Yes, all of those js, png, etc. are in `wwwroot` where they are supposed to be. Before the upload, the directory is completely empty in both cases. I tried both, this is the state I last left the file in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From comparing your screenshots, I can see a lot more files and fewer folders in your DevOps Pipelines version than in your manual version. It looks like your FTP task is uploading everything without putting it in folders.

Looking at your YAML file, you have `preservePaths: false` in the FTP task. According to the [task's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/ftp-upload?view=azure-devops):

> **preservePaths**: Preserve file paths (Required)
> If selected, the relative local directory structure is recreated under the remote directory where files are uploaded. Otherwise, files are uploaded directly to the remote directory without creating additional subdirectories.
> For example, suppose your source folder is: `/home/user/source/` and contains the file: `foo/bar/foobar.txt`, and your remote directory is: `/uploads/`.
> If selected, the file is uploaded to: `/uploads/foo/bar/foobar.txt`. Otherwise, to: `/uploads/foobar.txt`
> Default value: `false`

You should instead set `preservePaths: true`, so that the original directory structure (such as your `.png` and `.js` files being in `wwwroot`) is maintained.

```yaml
- task: FtpUpload@2
  inputs:
    credentialsOption: 'inputs'
    serverUrl: 'ftp://ftp.xxxxxxx.com/'
    username: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    password: 'xxxxxxxxxx'
    rootDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/s'  
    filePatterns: '**'
    remoteDirectory: '/'
    clean: false
    cleanContents: false
    preservePaths: true
    trustSSL: false
```

If you don't mind clearing the FTP server every time, then setting `cleanContents: true` might be a good idea, as it ensures that you don't have any files clashing with each other.

EDIT: following some investigation on your part, you discovered that the `/s` suffix is necessary on the root directory, so I have added it to my answer.

Comment: I'm running the pipeline again now with `preservePaths: true`. The yaml was in the last state I left it after lots of trial and error with different combinations of settings. I was getting a bit punchy after repeated failures

Comment: ok that sort of worked. it created the files in the correct directories but under a root directory called `s` I recall this being where my problems started a while back, I've only recently comeback to this

Comment: @djack109 The `s` part sounds a lot like the final section of the path in the DevOps pipeline: it's copying the root directory itself as well. Have you checked with `ls` or something that there is no additional `s` folder in `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`? You can also try [turning debugging on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/ftp-upload?view=azure-devops#q-im-having-issues-with-publishing-my-artifacts-how-can-i-view-the-detailed-logs).

Comment: I dont think I can get at that folder. How would I do that, It's all within azure. I don't actually specify any directory information I just use the directory variables azure provides, and it was a mission working out what those were.

Comment: You can have a `bash` task and put `ls "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"` in there for example. Most of my DevOps pipelines debugging ends up being a lot of that...

Comment: I've just gone through the build logs and saw this `2021-01-15T10:01:25.2812038Z ##[debug]Creating source directory: '/home/vsts/work/1/s'` the `.../s` appears quite a lot and not something I put in

Comment: @djack109 I think the `s` stands for `staging` (there is often an `a` one as well).

Comment: there is an `a` and `b` and `s` which I can understand while doing the checkout/build but how do I stop them appearing in my ftp ?

Comment: Total guess but would this work `"$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/s"` ?

Comment: @djack109 I'm unsure, because if you `echo "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"`, I think it will end in `/s` already (although it's worth just `echo`ing variables and `ls`ing directories.

Comment: That worked `"$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/s"`publishes straight to the root. I went back to the azure documentation and could find nothing about this, with that said tho, there is a lot of documentation and its quite possibly squirreled away somewhere I haven't looked. I hope this article and discussion helps someone else